# method return boolean form xor

Tags: java, boolean-logic, xor

Using java, I have a method:

```
boolean shouldPointBeAdded(boolean excludePoint, shapeContainsPoint){
    return excludePoint ^ shapeContainsPoint;
}
```

used as:

```
if(shouldPointBeAdded(excludePoint, shape.contains(point))
```

This is used as an if condition, however it doesn't perform the same way as if I were to do XOR directly as the if condition.

Note: I've wrapped the XOR in a method for testing and readability.

When running the unit test cases, the asserts do not return the correct value when using the method shouldPointBeAdded(), however they do return the correct value when XOR is used directly in the if condition.

Thoughts??

Thanks.

UPDATE:
Making shouldPointBeAdded() static solves the perceived problem, so I think the issues lies in with the mocking of the test objects.

Comment: How is this compiling? You need `boolean` before `shapeContainsPoint`.

Comment: Your code is not working. Besides that you do not use the method parameters in the body.

Comment: I used your method (correcting the errors the others already remarked) and had a successfull test. Please correct your code and if it still fails then show us your unit tests.

Comment: Where are boolean1 and boolean2 defined, instead of these you should be using the parameters being passed to the method.

Comment: boolean1 and boolean2 were a mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mock \ spy'd object was incorrectly set up.
It wasn't initialised with the behaviour at the right time and with an incorrect object; this is what I believe from what I've observed.

So, it was:

```
when(spy.shouldPointBeAdded(excludePoints, shape.contains(mock(Point.class)))).thenCallRealMethod();
```

I change it to:

```
when(spy.shouldPointBeAdded(excludePoints, shape.contains(point)).thenCallRealMethod();
```

exlcludePoints and shape are real objects, not mocks, that are passed into a set up method, and point is a test class member variable.
point is assigned as necessary just before it is used.

```
for(Point pointInGrid : buildTenByTenGrid()) {
            point = pointInGrid;
            if(objectUnderTest.shouldPointBeAdded(excludePoints, shape.contains(point))) {
                pointsInShape.add(point);
            }
        }
```

Tests working as expected now.